# Excel: Adding a regression line into an existing graph with multiple lines

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I'm having a line graph of production waste corresponding to four different production sites. However, I want to include a trend line (regression) in the same graph. This regression should conduct a trend line of the total production waste of the production sites.

I.e. if production site 1 through 4 has a production waste of 2 units each month, I want the regression to be a flat line at y = 8.

Is this possible? I'm using Excel 2010.

EDIT: I've realized that it is not possible to make a regression line without converting the regular graph into a scatter plot first (or is it..?). However the initial question remains.

Comment: The screenshot in my post below shows a line chart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the total of all sites as a data series to the line chart and then add a trend line for the total series. Format the total series to show no line and only the trend line will be visible. In the screenshot the dotted line is a polynomial trend line on the total series, which has been hidden by formatting with no line.

[image]

Comment: Thanks alot for this. I could easily adapt this answer to better suit some similar problems I've encountered due to how well explained the answer was.